# Why does "ls *" take so much longer than "ls"?

Tags: filesystems, performance, ls, time

I have a couple of files in a directory:

```
$ ls | wc -l
9376
```

Can anybody explain why there is such a huge time difference in using `ls *` and `ls`?

```
$ time ls > /dev/null
real    0m0.118s
user    0m0.106s
sys     0m0.011s
```

and

```
$ time ls * > /dev/null
real    1m32.602s
user    0m0.233s
sys     0m0.438s
```

okay, this is a drastic example and maybe enhanced because the directory is on a general parallel file system (GPFS). But I can also see a significant slowdown on a local file system.

**EDIT:**

```
$ time ls -l > /dev/null
real    0m58.772s
user    0m0.113s
sys     0m0.452s
$ time ls -l * > /dev/null
real    1m19.538s
user    0m0.252s
sys     0m0.461s
```

and I should add that in my example there are no sub directories:

```
$ diff <(ls) <(ls *)
$
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When you run `ls` without arguments, it will just open a directory, read all the contents, sort them and print them out.

When you run `ls *`, first the shell expands `*`, which is effectively the same as what the simple `ls` did, builds an argument vector with all the files in the current directory and calls `ls`. `ls` then has to process that argument vector and for each argument, and calls `access(2)`¹ the file to check it's existence. Then it will print out the same output as the first (simple) `ls`. Both the shell's processing of the large argument vector and `ls`'s will likely involve a lot of memory allocation of small blocks, which can take some time. However, since there was little `sys` and `user` time, but a lot of `real` time, most of the time would have been spent waiting for disk, rather than using CPU doing memory allocation.

Each call to `access(2)` will need to read the file's inode to get the permission information. That means a lot more disk reads and seeks than simply reading a directory. I do not know how expensive these operations are on your GPFS, but as the comparison you've shown to `ls -l` which has a similar run time to the wildcard case, the time needed to retrieve the inode information appears to dominate. If GPFS has a slightly higher latency than your local filesystem on each read operation, we would expect it to be more pronounced in these cases.

The difference between the wildcard case and `ls -l` of 50% could be explained by the ordering of inodes on the disk. If the inodes were laid out successively in the same order as the filenames in the directory and `ls -l` stat(2)ed the files in directory order before sorting, `ls -l` would possibly read most of the inodes in a sweep. With the wildcard, the shell will sort the filenames before passing them to `ls`, so `ls` will likely read the inodes in a different order, adding more disk head movement.

It should be noted that your `time` output will not include the time taken by the shell to expand the wildcard.

If you really want to see what's going on, use `strace(1)`:

```
strace -o /tmp/ls-star.trace ls *
strace -o /tmp/ls-l-star.trace ls -l *
```

and have a look which system calls are being performed in each case.

¹ I don't know if `access(2)` is actually used, or something else such as `stat(2)`. But both probably require an inode lookup (I'm not sure if `access(file, 0)` would bypass an inode lookup.)

Comment: Good answer, I was just about to post a similar one :)  But yeah, this is correct, it's all about efficiencies in the looping, with `ls` it can just ask the file system "what are the children of the inode for `pwd`" where as with `ls *` it has to ask "what are the children (and what is the file) of the inode `a`" followed by b, c, d, etc etc.  One query vs many.

Comment: @N J *one query vs many* is a good summary so far. @camh: thanks for the detailed answer. I posted the output of `ls -l` as well (still about 30 seconds less than `ls *`)

Comment: @Sebastian As camh stated, `ls -l` will take longer than `ls` as it has to `stat(2)` each file to get information about timestamps/owner information/permissions, etc.

Comment: Don't forget, `*` globs to *all* entries in the current directory that don't start with a period -- including the names of subdirectories. Which will then be `ls`'ed.

Comment: @camh: I tested a bit more (see my edits) and found that: `ls` < `ls -l` < `ls -l *` < `ls *` (I always ran it three times). With your explanation, I don't understand why `ls -l *` is faster than `ls *`

Comment: @Sebastian: I'm not sure why you are seeing those differences between `ls *` and `ls -l *`, unless some cache effects are in play. I've updated my answer with how you can see what system calls are being run.

Comment: nice! You're right, I'm not seeing this difference on a local file system. Anyway, `strace` reveals that `ls -l *` is using `lstat64` and `getxattr`, whereas `ls *` is just using `stat64` and `lstat64`.

Comment: On the other hand, `ls` uses `getdents64` and not `(l)stat64` (as `ls *` is doing). `getdents64` doesn't have a file name argument. On *GPFL*, `ls -l` uses another function called `readlink`, which may be faster than `stat64`. thanks a lot!

Comment: @camh: the idea of using strace is neat. However, the `*-expansion` part will be performed by the englobing bash, and therefore will not appear in the strace output (and it is probably the most expensive part). An alternative would be to `strace -f bash -c 'ls'` and `strace -f bash -c 'ls *'` (so the "*" is quoted and therefore will only occur within the sub-bash, instead of being done by the englobing shell prior to  (and "outside of) calling strace) and compare the two. (note also the `-f` to trace child processes, which will happen as the "bash -c" will fork a "ls" process)